# Displaying the category number (or column #)

Tags: php

I've a simple question. I've been trying to display the category number (or column number which are same thing here) in this code.

```
$cat[1] = ["A"];
$cat[2] = ["B"];


 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {


    $columns[1] = array_filter($row, function($col) use ($cat) {
        if(in_array($col, $cat[1])) {  
            return true;
        }
    });


    $columns[2] = array_filter($row, function($col) use ($cat) {
        if(in_array($col, $cat[2])) {  
            return true;
        }
    });


  $output[] = $columns;   
}

$table = <<<EOT
<table>
<tr>
<th>R1</th>
<th>R2</th>
</tr>
EOT;


foreach($output as $row) {
    $table.="<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column) {
        $table .="<td>";
        $values =   // count($column); // this is  where I need help.
        $table .= $values;
        $table .="</td>";
    }

    $table.="</tr>";

}
$table.="</table>";
echo $table;
```

I need help here: `$values = count($column);`   I couldn't figure out the right function to use. Instead of counting the contents of the category, I need category (column) number to displayed if it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need in your code is to get the key of your array element.

```
foreach ($output as $row) {
    $table .= "<tr>";

    // Add $key => here VVV
    foreach ($row as $key => $column) {
        $table .= "<td>";
        $values = $key;  // Because you only have 2 keys in your array this should be 1 or 2
        $table .= $values;
        $table .= "</td>";
    }

    $table .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: in the example code, I just included two columns/categories for simplicity. Would this  work for more categories? because I have more in the actual data. thanks.

Comment: I tried it, i got this errror : ( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..... on line 220.  Which is `foreach($row as $key => $column) {`

Comment: Your code example was not very clear as to what the columns are and why are you filtering them like this. It should work as long as you populate the keys e.g. `$columns[2]` when you make the columns.

Comment: thanks, Dharman. it works.  this code will show the $key even if the category is empty? in original code, i use count, and if it is empty, it shows zero.

Comment: I think you should explain more clearly what your full requirement is. There can't be an empty key, it can be zero, but it can't be empty.

Comment: I see. but it doesn't make sense like this, I got all numbers from 1 - 8 lined up in the html table. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I wanted to display category number if it's not empty.

Comment: What is the array_filter function doing? What is the purpose of `in_array($col, $cat[2]`? What is category and where do the values come from? I tried to extrapolate something from your question, but I still don't have the big picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The code categorizes the data, and displays them as such (I use implode to display data, and count to count the contents ). if empty, it gives blank.